# Scoping issues with Context Provider using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have been working on a React Context Provider, and trying to create a function within the Provider to pass along to components for use. However, when I attempt to write the function within the provider, it says that the variable with the type void cannot be passed onto value. When I do it this way, it does not throw this error:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

interface IUser {
    user: String;
    doSignup: (
        email: String,
        password: String,
        verifyPassword: String,
        name: String
    ) => void;
}

const doSignup = (
    email: String,
    password: String,
    verifyPassword: String,
    name: String
): void => {
    console.log(email, password, verifyPassword, name);
};

export const UserContext = createContext<IUser>({
    user: "",
    doSignup: doSignup,
});

const UserContextProvider: React.FC = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, doSignup }}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default UserContextProvider;
```

But doing it this way will also create scoping issues, because on other functions I will need access to the `setUser` method being created by `useState`. I also cannot use the `useState` hook outside of the component.

Trying to figure out the best way to do this, and coming up short.

Comment: Pass the set state function out as one of the values of the context. Also, your `doSignup` function should be defined inside the context if you want to also pass it as a value.

Comment: It mght be worth posting the code the way that you want it to be written, so that we can help fix the bug, rather than posting a working version and saying you don't want it to be like this. Can you update the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been throught the same problem. This works for me:

```js
interface IUserContext {
  foo: '';
  userData: {};
  updateFoo(foo: string): void;
  updateUserData(userData: Object): void;
}

export const UserFooContext = createContext<IUserContext>({
  foo: '',
  userData: {},
  updateFoo(foo: string) {
    return null;
  },
  updateUserData(userData: Object) {
    return null;
  },
});
```

Maybe you can use this schema in your context. I hope it helps

Comment: This looks like the missing ingredients in typing this out that I was missing. Thanks!